Jamod modbus tcp Executing transaction failed (tried 3 times)
I wrote an application using Spring Boot with Jamod to communicate with my UPS device. When I try to communicate with the device I'm getting wanted data but only once when I start my app, every next Scheduled for 60 secounds request fails with error Executing transaction failed. I tried debugging but everything seems fine for first request but every next request fails with that error. I set the connection timeout on my ups for 10s and in my app i also set it for 10s. When it was lower it also showed errors like Premature end of stream (header trunckted), End of Stream, End of Connection etc.
Reading registers function:
public Register[] readRegisters(int startingAddress, int quantity, int unitId) throws Exception {
        ReadMultipleRegistersRequest request = new ReadMultipleRegistersRequest(startingAddress, quantity);
        request.setUnitID(unitId);

        ModbusTCPTransaction transaction = new ModbusTCPTransaction(connection);
        transaction.setRequest(request);
        transaction.execute();

        ReadMultipleRegistersResponse response = (ReadMultipleRegistersResponse) transaction.getResponse();
        return response.getRegisters();
    }

Data logging function:
public void logDeviceDataPeriodically() {
        try {
            List<DeviceEntity> devices = deviceEntityRepository.findAll();
            for (DeviceEntity deviceEntity : devices) {
                String providerType = deviceEntity.getStatusProviderEntity().getProviderName();
                StatusProvider statusProvider = providerFactory.createProvider(providerType);
                if (statusProvider != null) {
                    statusProvider.connect();
                    DeviceData deviceData = new DeviceData();
                    deviceData.setInputVoltage(statusProvider.getInputVoltage());
                    deviceData.setOutputVoltage(statusProvider.getOutputVoltage());
                    deviceData.setLoadPercentage(statusProvider.getLoadPercentage());
                    deviceData.setTime(statusProvider.getTime());
                    deviceData.setTimestamp(LocalDateTime.now());
                    deviceData.setDeviceEntity(deviceEntity);
                    deviceDataRepository.save(deviceData);
                } else {
                    System.err.println("Unknown provider - " + providerType);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace(); // Handle or log the exception appropriately
        }
    }

getInputVoltage()
public double getInputVoltage() throws Exception {
        int vInStartingAdress = 0x0084; int quantity = 1; int unitId = 1;
        return modbusTcpConnector.readRegisters(vInStartingAdress, quantity, unitId)[0].getValue() / 10.0;
    }

If anybody has similar problem with Jamod library please share any fixes, thanks in advance.
I tried to make a new project with this library everything was the same. I also tried to use different libraries to get expected results but none of them worked for me. As far as so jamod is the best for my requirements.

You wrote (in your answer): thread can be closed Seems to me that you are unfamiliar with how stackoverflow works. Have you taken the [tour] ? If you think that your question (and answer) will help others, then maybe add the corrected code for method readRegisters to your answer as I think that will make clearer the required changes. If you really think that thread can be closed then you should delete the question.

Never mind I just had an epiphany. The answer is I was missing implementation of my connect() function and connection.close() inside readRegisters function... thread can be closed
